# Taigalach for Rosh HaShana

Tags: minhag, food, rosh-hashanah-new-year

Many people have the Minhag to eat [Taigalach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teiglach) on Rosh Hashana. To the best of my knowledge Taigalach is made with walnuts. How does this jive with the Minhag not to eat nuts on Rosh Hashana since Egoz ≈ Chait?

Comment: Perhaps the minhagim are mutually exclusive. Does anyone hold of both?

Comment: Many are lenient with nuts mixed in foods.

Comment: @sam who? Source?

Comment: Be'er Moshe 3:97

Comment: Many bakeries that I have seen don't use real nuts. They look more like flattened "soup nuts". They are, essentially tiny slightly hardened, sometimes half-fried or over-baked dough "nuggets" stuck together by honey-"glue". Definitely not as tasty. I'd much rather eat good baklava.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Yad Yitzchak 1:208 who discusses nuts mixed in a tavshil if it loses its classification of a nut. http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=855&st=&pgnum=198

See Be'er Moshe 3:97 as well who writes don't yell at those who are meikel.

http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14710&st=&pgnum=148&hilite=